# How do I shutdown a socket from a request within Flask?

Tags: python, sockets, flask

I'm trying to be bad.

I have a Python Flask application that's used by a lot of other services, and I want to simulate it being ***unreliable***.  I'm trying to implement something vaguely like a lightweight [Chaos Monkey](https://netflix.github.io/chaosmonkey/) by causing this critical Flask application to randomly disconnect incoming requests, so that we can observe what happens in *other* applications when their requests are unpredictably dropped.

> (*Why?* I have real-world servers running these Flask apps in industrial environments with *extremely* poor wireless network connectivity.  I need to demonstrate that the *rest* of the system talking to these apps can reasonably recover even when the network drops most of the packets passing through it.  Statistically killing requests on an otherwise-stable connection seems like a pretty good technique for doing so.)

The first part of the code is pretty straightforward:  Add a `before_request` hook that randomly chooses whether this request is going to fail:

```py
PSEUDORANDOM = # ...custom repeatable RNG here...
THRESHOLD = # ...configurable reliability setting from 0 to 1...

@flask.before_request
def before_request_callback():
    if PSEUDORANDOM.random() > THRESHOLD:
        # ...what to do here?
```

Importantly, I don't want to return a `500 Internal Server Error` or a `4xx Sorry` response.  I don't want *any* response to be sent back to the caller *at all* — I want to be able to write `socket.close()` — or better yet, `socket.shutdown()`.  I want to simulate a crash or a major application failure or a network failure.

But I can't figure out how to get access to the underlying socket itself; it's wrapped in enough layers of objects that I can't find whichever one is actually holding it.  I've read through the [source code](https://github.com/pallets/werkzeug) of the `Request` classes in the `werkzeug` package, and it has almost everything you could want — except the socket.  The closest I can get is the `Request.stream` property, but invoking its `close()` method doesn't seem to do anything at all.  Scouring StackOverflow questions for the last half hour hasn't yielded anybody else doing this either, apparently.

**So how do I access the underlying socket so I can make this Flask application randomly appear to fail?**

Comment: I'd suggest to carefully read the introduction to WSGI and understand the implications - even if you think you don't need it.

Comment: I’ve read the WSGI spec more than once. Its abstractions are nice most of the time, but for this kind of problem, they get in the way more than they help. I need to do low-level things with the underlying sockets, and I’m trying to avoid ditching Flask and just using `HttpServer` directly because of how much of the code already uses Flask, but that really _is_ the level of control I need — to be able to intercept — and potentially _break_ — every incoming TCP connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[This article](https://www.ajg.id.au/2018/01/01/mutual-tls-with-python-flask-and-werkzeug/) ([still reachable via the wayback machine](https://web.archive.org/web/20210928235937/https://www.ajg.id.au/2018/01/01/mutual-tls-with-python-flask-and-werkzeug/)) demonstrates a way of accessing the raw socket while processing a request.
[Shutting down](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.shutdown) the socket will then trigger a connection timed our error on the client side.

```
from flask import Flask, request
import socket
import werkzeug


class ErrorTestingWSGIRequestHandler(werkzeug.serving.WSGIRequestHandler):
    def make_environ(self):
        environ = super(ErrorTestingWSGIRequestHandler, self).make_environ()
        environ['socket'] = self.connection
        return environ


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/')
def main():
    return '<a href="/error">Fail now!</a>'


@app.route('/error')
def error():
    request.environ["socket"].shutdown(socket.SHUT_RDWR)
    return "not shown"


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(request_handler=ErrorTestingWSGIRequestHandler)
```

Comment: This is exactly the kind of answer I was looking for, and it works well! I knew the socket had to be hidden somewhere inside Flask or Werkzeug, and I'm glad someone knew of a way to pull it out! My implementation now uses a configurable reliability level in `before_request` to randomly shutdown the socket, which is a far better solution for reliability testing than just raising HTTP `5xx` errors. With this, I can simulate unreliability at the TCP level, which is close enough to the transport layer that we can now actually test how callers react to an unreliable network.